# What is the minimum permission for session folder in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

My `application/config/config.php` is looks like,

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

1. I am using amazon linux server. If i
   have set `session` folder permission to `777` then it is working
   fine but if i have change to any other permission it is return
   `Message: Session: Configured save path 'application/session' is not writable by the PHP process.`, even `775` is  not working. I need to
   secure my site. What is the minimum permission for it and how can i
   use it?
2. If i need to change text of any file like text from PHP, then what is the minimum permission for it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. The user PHP runs as needs to read and write files. Everybody else don't.

Comment: Need 777 for session folder too? It is secure?

Comment: Do you know what the three numbers mean? It's "user / group / others". Group and Others don't need any kind of access when there's a single user involved.

Comment: Yes I know that. If i am using 770 means all access of owner and groups but don't for public. and session file has ownership of same user. but it return `Message: Session: Configured save path 'application/session' is not writable by the PHP process`.

Comment: Well... Your question is "What is the minimum permission for session folder in codeIgniter?" and the answer is "give permission only to the user"; other different users from the same group don't need access at all. Perhaps you're simply asking how to solve some specific problem and I was misled by the title.

Comment: Okay, but it not working so i have to know that what permission is required for session folder rather than 777, because it is only working with 777.